# Why I can't apply => to function with void?

Tags: nim-lang

Sugar works with `map`

```
import sugar 

proc map2*[T, R](list: openArray[T]; cb: proc (x: T): R): seq[R] =
  for v in list: result.add(cb(v))
  result
  
echo @[1, 2].map2((v) => v*v)
```

But not with `each`, seems like it somehow related to `void`, is there a way to make it work with `void` too?

```
import sugar 

proc each2*[T](list: openArray[T]; cb: proc (x: T): void): void =
  for v in list: cb(v)

@[1, 2].each2((v) => echo v)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had much luck with `sugar.=>` personally. This will do what you want, and isn't much more verbose:

```
proc each2*[T](list: openArray[T]; cb: proc (x: T): void): void =
  for v in list: cb(v)

@[1, 2].each2(proc(v: auto) = echo v)
```

[This RFC](https://github.com/nim-lang/RFCs/issues/232) is proposing proper lambda support, which should give us a succinct way to write anonymous procs that work everywhere.